# Setting up properly DropDownListFor in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I use a ADO.NET Entity framework to map my DB into Model in my application. I've setup my ViewModel for registration like following:

```
public class UserRegistrationViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
        public SelectList Countries { get; set; }

    }
```

The specific part here is that I want to fill up my dropdown list with Countries from my DBContext which looks like this:

```
Connection.ctx.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName).ToList();
```

As you can see the countries are a list now, and in my view I would like to set up a dropdown list using Html helper class like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Countries);
```

And this is how I've mapped my model in the view:

```
@model WebApplication2.ViewModels.UserRegistrationViewModel
```

How do I properly setup the dropdown list (i.e. select list) so that I can display data from the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property in your viewModel to save the id of selected country:

```
public class UserRegistrationViewModel
{
    //
    public int SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Countries { get; set; }

}
```

I'm going to guess at the time to set Countries property you are doing something like this:

```
var countries=Connection.ctx.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName).ToList();
//...
viemodel.Countries=new SelectList(countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
```

Then in your view you can do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountryId, Model.Countries)
```

Comment: Hey it shows me this error when I try this method:'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Countries_72FA95A5B14211F073C8C11B1E3587265F1CE9063C9540E555C16AC7031F4887' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'.

Comment: What is the the PK in your Country entity?

Comment: Replace `Id` by `CountryId`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You need two properties: one to hold the selected value and one to hold your select list options:

```
public string Country { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryOptions { get; set; }
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountryOptions)
```

You don't need an actual `SelectList`. In fact, it's preferable if you don't. Razor will automatically create a `SelectList` and select the appropriate value.

Comment: and how do I fill the country options with the actual records from my DB? :D I can't use the method where I simply convert all of the records to list lol

Comment: You just select them into a collection of `SelectListItem`s, i.e. `db.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Iso2, Text = m.Name })`. (Obviously, you'd change the property names to what's actually on your `Country` entity.)